# Service file exists but is not found by systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I have created a systemd service file and placed it in `/etc/systemd/system/anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service`. I ran `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl daemon-reexec` and rebooted the system.

- `systemctl enable anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper` results in

  ```
  Failed to enable unit: Unit file anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service does not exist.
  ```
- `systemctl start anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper` results in

  ```
  Failed to start anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service: Unit anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service not found.
  ```
- `ls -lh /etc/systemd/system/anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service` outputs

  ```
  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 440 Mar 19 12:08 /etc/systemd/system/anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service
  ```
- `cd /root && systemd-analyze verify anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service` has an exit code of 0 and prints no output.
- `mount` shows

  ```
  /dev/sda2 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
  ```
- There are no other mounts touching `/usr` or `/etc`.
- The contents of the service file are:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Anfragen 3D Konfigurations Mapper Service
  After=network.target

  [Service]
  Restart=always
  ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/podman stop anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper
  ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/podman rm anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --rm --name anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper-app -p 10010:10000 anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper-app:0.0.1
  ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- All above commands were run as the `root` user.
- Operating System: CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core)
- Systemd version: 239
- Linux kernel: `Linux version 4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3) (GCC))`
- I vaguely remember having a similar problem with another service file some months ago which just magically started working after a few hours of poking around and renaming the service file back and forth.

I'm interested in two things:

- How does one debug such a problem?
- What is wrong?

Comment: are there other .service files there?  If you copy one of them is it "detectable" by systemd?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As hinted at by @JdeBP wrong SELinux file labels are the reason for the behavior. The `.` character in the output of `ls` indicates that there is a security context set for the file. So be attentive to the `.` in the `ls` output!

`cd /etc/systemd/system && ls -lhZ some-other-service.service anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service` prints

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0        440 Mar 19 12:08 anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 457 Feb 24 11:42 some-other-service.service
```

It can be seen that the other service file has the `systemd_unit_file_t` label, while the broken service doesn't. This can be fixed with `restorecon anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service`. After this the labels look as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 440 Mar 19 12:08 anfragen-3dkonfig-mapper.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 457 Feb 24 11:42 some-other-service.service
```

systemd now behaves as expected.

Comment: how does restorecon know how to label the service file correctly?

Comment: I don't know! You may start a new question about that.

Comment: How do you modify these headers in a nuanced way? Or is placing the file in the right folder and running `restorecon file` "The Way" to do it?

Comment: See `chcon`. But know what you are doing. A `restorecon` will just trample over your individual changes. So I guess ideally one should write selinux rule files and then rely on `restorecon`.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> -rw-r--r--.
> ```

SELinux restrictions are making life complex for you.

Comment: You were right, SELinux file labels were the problem.

Comment: Is that only from GNU `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

I just spent an hour chasing this issue after moving some of the service files around. The symlink in `/lib/systemd/system` was pointing to the correct file, but the symlink in `/etc/systemd/system` was not (its target no longer existed). I removed this offending (broken) symlink, replaced it with the correct one, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue, we use rootless podman on centos7.

Container were not started after reboot, the services were not found. But before reboot the services were enabled and present in /etc/systemd/system. Services were created via syslink ln -s from /home/user to /etc/systemd

When you run after reboot `Systemctl status nameOfService.service` it returns "Unit servicename.service could not be found."

When you run `systemctl daemon-reload` the service is present again.

One possible solution is to create a syslink ln -s from /root/ to /etc/systemd/system - after reboot your service will still exist.

Better solution

- Create your own service that executes daemon-reload and starts your service

Create startServiceOnBoot.sh script with daemon-reload and start of your service

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload    
    sudo systemctl start nameOfService.service
```

Make sh script executable `chmod +x startServiecOnBoot.sh`

Create your service /etc/systemd/system/serviceStarter.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Daemon Reloader
...

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/startServiecOnBoot.sh
...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable service on boot `systemctl enable serviceStarter.service` you can also check if starting your new service serviceStarter.service actually starts nameOfService.service aswell.

I tried After= and .timer with services in systemd but were not successfull. For debugging $systemd-analyze blame