# systemd template not working: filename@arg1.service not found

Tags: systemd

I am trying to run python file with arguments from systemd service. So the service file supposed to take argument and pass it to python file in "Execstart".

Here is my systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=test Service On %I
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user_name/directory
User=user_name
Type=idle

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user_name/directory/test.py %I
Restart=no
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

test.py:

```
import sys
print("arguments: "+str(sys.argv))
```

I tried with following commands:

```
sudo systemctl start $(systemd-escape --template test@.service "arg1")
```

also,

```
sudo systemctl start test@arg1.service
```

I get error:
Unit test@arg1.service not found

Comment: You should locate your systemd service in `/etc/systemd/system`. Try: `sudo cp /path/to/test@.service /etc/systemd/system`

Comment: Are you update systemd with systemctl daemon-reload?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon yes, it is /etc/systemd/system

Comment: @gapsf yes, i did

Comment: systemctl enable test@.service ?

Comment: @sovon If you have SELinux check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573760/service-file-exists-but-is-not-found-by-systemd

Comment: It is not clear from this question what your unit file is named or where it is located. Clear information on those points in your question would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need the service file to be named according to the argument you need :

- NOT `/etc/systemd/system/test.service`
- BUT `/etc/systemd/system/test@arg1.service`